# Update contact record then use in a decision split

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

In Journey Builder, I know it's possible to update a contact record on a DE linked through Contact Builder but is it possible to then use that updated data in a decision split later on in the Journey? The contact record is being updated on a DE that is not used for the Journey audience on the fire event.

Essentially, I want to split my contacts in three groups A, B, C right when they enter the journey. Then send each group down different paths using decision splits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible if you use *Contact Data* in your decision split.

> Journey data preserves the state of a contact's data at the moment an entry event fires, facilitating the use of that data throughout a journey. Contact data captures the data values in the event source data extension at the time when Journey Builder evaluates it.
> (Source: [Journey and Contact Data](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/using_event_data/))

Having the data stored in another data extension isn't a problem as long as the data extension is correctly linked in *Contact Builder - Data Designer*. If specific values need to be compared in order to retrieve the correct record, you can do this with the new *Expression Builder* that is live since the August '17 release.

**Related documentation:**

- [Journey and Contact Data](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/using_event_data/)
- [August '17 Release Notes - Journey Builder](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/release_notes/august_2017_release/journey_builder/)

Comment: This was my understanding as well, but my Journey doesn't appear to be working in this way. However, looking deeper in the account (that I inherited) I notice the Contact Data in question is linked to the contact record through a Population DE. If the subscriber is not in that population DE at time of decision split evaluation, would that be causing the issue?

Comment: Yes that would be a problem if you select the path to read from that population. Another problem with synchronized data extensions is the synchronization delay which requires you to have enough time in a wait activity between updating the contact or other object in salesforce sales/service cloud and using the data in a decision split.